# Apache Documentroot setting in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, apache2

I have attempted to change my documentroot settings in httpd.conf from the default directory to c:\www and then I restart apache. However no matter how many times I have tried this apache doesnt change the default directory.

Has anyone had this problem before? Does someone know how I can change this?

Answer (score 1):

I just went through this same #$%#!! headache on a newly installed Windows 7 OS with newly installed browser with no configuration.  I installed Apache, it tested fine.  I installed PHP and changed my httpd.conf file and it acted at yours appeared to act:

solution: the PHP module was failing (as per eventlog) and apache server therefore failing to start too.  Firefox was visiting a cached version of the webpage so it looked like I was still getting the default Apache page when in reality the page was down.  I uninstalled PHP and Apache started working again.